# Rails 4, how to update a model field from a different controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to update an invoice fields, when checking out in the carts controller. These must be present when checking out, or it should fail. However, I can't get it to update, much less validate them.
Here is my code:

cart show view:

```
<div class = "row">
    <div class = "col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-6 text-left">
        <strong>Customer: </strong>
        <%= collection_select(:invoice, :customer_id, @customers, :id, :full_name, {:prompt => 'Please Select'}, class: 'form-control') %>
    </div>
    <div class = "col-lg-3 ext-left">
        <strong>Seller: </strong>
        <%= collection_select(:invoice, :employee_id, @employees, :id, :full_name, {:prompt => 'Please Select'}, class: 'form-control') %>
    </div>
    <div class = "col-lg-12 text-right">
        <%= form_tag carts_checkout_path, method: :post do |f| %>
            <%= submit_tag 'Complete', class: 'btn btn-success' %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

carts controller:

```
class CartsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @invoice = current_invoice
    @invoice_products = current_invoice.invoice_products
    @customers = Customer.all
    @employees = Employee.all
  end
  def checkout 
    current_invoice.customer_id = params[:customer_id]
    current_invoice.employee_id = params[:employee_id]
    current_invoice.save
    redirect_to current_invoice
  end
end
```

current_invoice is the current session's invoice, related to the cart. It redirects correctly, but doesn't update.

in the invoices controller:

```
def invoice_params
  params.require(:invoice).permit(:invoice_number, :customer_id, :invoice_date, :invoice_status_id, :employee_id, invoice_products_attributes: [:id, :invoice_id, :product_id, :price, :tax, :discount, :value])
end
```

Can anyone please help me in identifying where I am going wrong? Could it be my approach is not even valid?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it.

```
current_invoice.update_attributes(customer_id: params[:invoice][:customer_id], employee_id: params[:invoice][:employee_id])
```

Also in view, changed location of form_tag:

```
<div class = "row">
    <%= form_tag carts_checkout_path, method: :post do |f| %>
        <div class = "col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-6 text-left">
            <strong>Cliente: </strong>
            <%= collection_select(:invoice, :customer_id, @customers, :id, :full_name, {:prompt => 'Favor Seleccionar'}, class: 'form-control') %>
        </div>
        <div class = "col-lg-3 ext-left">
            <strong>Vendedor: </strong>
            <%= collection_select(:invoice, :employee_id, @employees, :id, :full_name, {:prompt => 'Favor Seleccionar'}, class: 'form-control') %>
        </div>
        <div class = "col-lg-12 text-right">
            <%= submit_tag 'Completar', class: 'btn btn-success' %>
        </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The type of functionality you're after is considered "business logic" and should be implemented in the model and called from the controller.

You can define a method in a model:

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base

  def update_invoice(cust_id, emp_id)
    if self.update_attributes(:customer_id => cust_id], :employee_id = emp_id])
      puts "Success!
    else
     puts "Failed to update record. Handle the error."
  end
end
```

You can call `my_method` from `carts_controller.rb` like this:

```
def update
  # all your regular update logic here

  # replace the bit of code that saves the cart with something like this:

  respond_to do |format|
    if(current_invoice.update_invoice(params[:customer_id], params[:employee_id])
      if(@cart.update(cart_params))
        format.html { redirect_to @activity, notice: 'Activity was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @activity }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @activity.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Also, note the use of `update_attributes` rather than `save`. Bear in mind that `update_attributes` will return `false` if you run into any problems updating (e.g. one or more validations failed). Don't confuse `update_attributes` with the singular `update_attribute` which updates a single field and will *not* run validations.

Comment: I changed to using update_attributes, but it didn't work. I tried to think on how to implement your solution, but I think I can't, because I don't have a Cart Model, it is just a controller that manipulates the invoice and invoice_product models. I used this guide: https://richonrails.com/articles/building-a-shopping-cart-in-ruby-on-rails

Comment: Sorry, answer updated. You don't need a Cart model. You can call any method from any model by first getting an instance of the model, which you already have in the form of `current_invoice`.

Comment: Thanks, the update attributes worked. But I think what is really wrong is the view. I tried this code and it updated, so it means the params have no customer_id nor employee_id: current_invoice.update_attributes(customer_id: 1, employee_id: params[:employee_id])

Comment: Do you have something like `<div class="debug">
    <%= yield %>
    <%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
</div>` at the bottom of your view? If not, add that code and you can see what params are being passed.

Comment: I checked and effectively the params does not include those values. I read all over and I should be able to access the values through params[:invoice][:customer_id], but the params are not there, so I get an error saying there is no [] method for nil

Comment: I downvoted because the model code is wrong. You shouldn't be returning data to a controller directly and it won't have access to naked params. It's a great answer (about biz logic), but the model code is misleading

Answer (score 0):

> Could it be my approach is not even valid

Your approach is definitely valid, it's great that you're using sessions in this way.

I'd do it slightly differently:

```
#config/routes.rb
resource :cart, except: [:edit, :new, :create], path_names: { update: "checkout" }
```

This will give you the following paths:

```
#url.com/cart -> carts#show (here you can invoke a cart if one doesn't exist)
#url.com/cart/checkout #-> POST to "update" method in carts controller
#url.com/cart/ (method: :delete) -> DELETE to "destroy" cart (refresh)
```

--

```
#app/controllers/carts_controller.rb
class CartsController < ApplicationController
   before_action :setup_cart

   def show
      @cart = current_cart #-> products called from this. I don't know how you're linking them
      @customers = Customer.all
      @employees = Employee.all
   end

   def update
      @invoice = Invoice.find_or_create_by(id: current_card.id)
      @invoice.update update_params
      redirect_to cart_path
   end

   def destroy
      current_cart = nil
      redirect_to carts_path, notice: "Cart Cleared"
   end

   private

   def setup_cart
     current_cart ||= sessions[:cart]
   end

   def update_params
      params.require(:cart).permit(:customer_id, :employee_id)
   end
end
```

Now, to update the cart, you'll want to take note from `MarsAtomic`'s answer. *However* it *must* be noted that **naked params are not available in the model**.

If you use `update_attributes`, or just plain `update`, you'll need to do the following:

```
#app/models/cart.rb
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :products
   belongs_to :employee
   belongs_to :customer

   #validations here
   #callbacks here (what MarsAtomic refers to as business logic)
   before_save :do_something, only: :update

   private

   def do_something
      #something here
      #params appended to current instance of object
      #eg self.customer_id
   end
end
```

I'd also go more succinct in your view:

```
#app/views/carts/show.html.erb
<div class = "row">
    <%= form_tag cart_checkout_path, method: :patch do |f| %>
        <% options = [["cliente", "customer"], ["vendedor", "employee"]] %>
        <% options.each do |name, type| %>
             <%= content_tag :strong, "#{name.titleize}:" %>
             <%= collection_select :cart, eval(":#{type}_id"), instance_variable_get("@#{type.pluralize}"), :id, :full_name, {:prompt => 'Favor Seleccionar'}, class: 'form-control') %>      
        <% end %>
        <% content_tag :div, class: "col-lg-12 text-right" do %>
            <%= submit_tag 'Completar', class: 'btn btn-success' %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```