# Rails: How to Update One Model from Another Controller (Unpermitted Parameters)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails app where, when a new user is created with an email that matches the `client_email` field in an existing `loan`, the corresponding loan needs to be updated to belong to that user.

In concordance with SO posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33049573/rails-4-how-to-update-a-model-field-from-a-different-controller) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44627378/rails-update-model-from-another-controller) I tried to implement this by having an `update_client` method in my `loan.rb` file like this:

```
  def update_client(client_id)
    self.update_attributes(client_id: client_id)
  end
```

So in my `registrations_controller.rb` I can call the method from there:

```
def create
    super

    if @user.persisted?
      Loan.all.each do |loan|
        if @user.email == loan.client_email
          loan.update_client(@user.id)
        end
      end
    end

  end


  def edit
    super

    if @user.persisted?
      Loan.all.each do |loan|
        if @user.email == loan.client_email
          loan.update_client(@user.id)
        end
      end
    end

  end
```

The problem is I'm still getting an unpermitted parameters error in my server log when it comes to the update of the loan:

> Unpermitted parameters: :subtitle, :first_name, :last_name, :phone, :confirm_password, :current_client, :buyer, :seller

You can tell that this is after the user is successfully created, but it's still preventing things from running glitch-free.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong here?

Comment: The message is related to the code where you are saving the user (it is not in the question), a bit of advice you can change the loop with something like `Loan.where(client_email: @user.email).update(client_id: @user.id)`

Comment: What is happening in the `super` call?  It seems more likely the error is coming from in there.